Limit Displayed Selected Items and Show Remaining Count
Up to 5 selected items are displayed by their text and if more than 5 items are selected, I want to show the first 5 items followed by "remaining count + " in a separate span to limit the selected items.
  function initializeSelect2WithCheckbox(selector) {
        $(selector).select2({
            templateResult: formatSelectionWithCheckbox,
            templateSelection: function(item) {
                return $('<span>').text(item.text);
            },
            closeOnSelect: false,
            allowClear: true
        }).on('select2:select', function(e) {
            var selectedValue = e.params.data.id;

            if (selectedValue === 'all') {
                var allOptions = $(selector).find('option').not('[value="all"]');
                var selectAllChecked = $(e.target).find('option[value="all"]').prop('selected');

                allOptions.prop('selected', selectAllChecked);
                $(selector).trigger('change');
            } else {
                updateSelectAll(selector);
            }
            $(selector).select2('close');
        }).on('select2:unselect', function(e) {
            if (e.params.data.id === 'all') {
                $(selector).val(null).trigger('change'); // Clear all on unselect
            } else {
                updateSelectAll(selector);
            }
        });
    }

Refer to this image
display i want to achieve

as documentation you can use
maximumSelectionLength: 3

see here
and for calculated remained selection you can use this:
$totalLength = $("li.select2-results__option--selectable").length();
$selectedLength = $("li.select2-results__option--selected").length();

$(".select2-selection__rendered").append("<span>unselected items is "+$totalLength-$selectedLength+" </span>");


I’ve already tried that, but my goal is to limit the display of the selected items (max of 5) in the input container, not to limit the selection of items itself. similar to what I showed in the attached image.
